# ros slam course

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I try to learn slam on [ros slam course](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Events/PR2BetaTraining/Videos/Tuesday).

But I only find the [first piece](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZ_-jAtGyZQ&feature=player_embedded) of slam course.

Where are the others which will teach how to implement slam functions on robot(not just simulation)?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10197/ros-slam-course/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData) on building a map from logged data, with instructions on how to record the needed data from your robot.

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-06-08**:
Thanks,but what I need is the slam course video on youtube or otherwhere, just like the first piece. I couldn't find the second,and third..etc